# VBA Error with intersect over 2 separate columns

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, intersect

I have an issue where when using the following line of code for a Worksheet_Change sub -

```
If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(7)) Or Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(11)) Is Nothing Then

GoTo SwiftExit
```

I get the 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error.

This is strange because just using

```
If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then

GoTo SwiftExit
```

works perfectly fine, adding the `Or` seems to break it. How can I get the above to work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim CurrSheetName As String

CurrSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(7)) Or Intersect(Target,ActiveSheet.Columns(11)) Is Nothing Then

GoTo SwiftExit

Else


Dim NameCount As Variant
Dim Row As Integer
Dim DateList As Range
Dim CalendarYear As Variant
Dim Month As Variant
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim NameCheck As String
Dim EADOccurances As Object
Dim T1Occurances As Object
Dim nr As Integer
Dim nb As Integer
Dim SheetName As String
Dim PersonName As String
Dim T1Error As String

ActiveSheet.Columns(25).ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Columns(26).ClearContents

Row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

CalendarYear = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
Set EADOccurances = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set T1Occurances = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If Not Sheet.Name = Info Or Not Sheet.Name = Data Then
SheetName = Sheet.Name
RowCount = 0
Set DateList = Sheet.Range("A2:A" & Row)

    For Each MonthNr In DateList
    RowCount = RowCount + 1

    MonthNr = Format(MonthNr, "mmmm")
    
    
    PersonName = Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 7).Value
    EADError = Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 5).Value
    T1Error = Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 9).Value
    
    
    
        For d = 0 To 11
        If MonthNr = CalendarYear(d) And Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 7).Value = CurrSheetName And Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 5).Value = "Yes" Then
    
        EADOccurances.Add MonthNr
        
        End If
        
        If MonthNr = CalendarYear(d) And Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 11).Value = CurrSheetName And Sheet.Cells(RowCount + 1, 9).Value = "Yes" Then
        
        T1Occurances.Add MonthNr
        
        End If
        
        Next
        
    
    
    Next

End If
Next

nr = 0

For i = 1 To EADOccurances.Count
Worksheets(CurrSheetName).Cells(i, 25) = EADOccurances(nr)
nr = nr + 1
Next i

nb = 0

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To T1Occurances.Count
Worksheets(CurrSheetName).Cells(x, 26) = T1Occurances(nb)
nb = nb + 1
Next x

With Worksheets(CurrSheetName)
Dim MyEADCount As Integer
Dim MyT1Count As Integer
Dim RowCounter As Integer

For d = 0 To 11

MyEADCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("Y1:Y1000"), CalendarYear(d))
MyT1Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("Z1:Z1000"), CalendarYear(d))

Worksheets(CurrSheetName).Range("U" & d + 2).Value = MyEADCount
Worksheets(CurrSheetName).Range("W" & d + 2).Value = MyT1Count

Next
End With
End If
```

Comment: Did you try `If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(7)) Is Nothing Or Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(11)) Is Nothing`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it then seems to disregard the statement all together and pushes straight to ```SwiftExit``` even if either ```Intersect``` is not nothing

Comment: You are using an OR operator, so if just one of them is nothing, the code goes into `SwiftExit `. Maybe you need an AND operator instead of OR? if you do `If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(7)) Is Nothing AND Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns(11)) Is Nothing` the code will go into `SwiftExit ` only if **both of them at the same time** are nothing

Comment: I followed that logic too, it returns the same error as before stating 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

Comment: Did you make sure you add `is nothing` to both statements when using AND? What is the address of `Target` when it fails (you can check it with `Target.Address`)?

Comment: I did add ```Is Nothing``` when using ```And```. ```Target``` is either a single cell outside of the intersect area or within the intersect area, that doesn't change anything and both receive the error output. Looks like it doesn't like being ```Nothing```...

Comment: Could you share the complete code? In a sheet module, you refer to the worksheet with the `Me` keyword e.g.:  `If Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(7)) Is Nothing And Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(11)) Is Nothing Then`. On a side note, the `Goto` keyword is kind of reserved for error handling. Most often you can rewrite the code without using it.

Comment: I added the rest of the code, I apologise if it isn't all that great, I didn't think it was all too useful to add the rest as I'm sure it will make some people cringe haha

Comment: There is no `SwiftExit` label. You could safely just use `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

What about getting rid of the OR altogether?

```
With Me 

    If Intersect(Target, Union(.Columns(7), .Columns(11))) Is Nothing Then
    
        GoTo SwiftExit
    
    Else
    
        ... do stuff
        
    End If
    
End With
```

Comment: WAit, that works, why does Union work here??

Comment: Union creates a single range that includes both columns. So you only have one test to perform.